# Can't register custom DBAL types

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, silex, dbal

I'm trying to register a bunch of custom **DBAL** types. When I run the **`migrations:diff`** I get the exception:

> **Fatal error**: Class 'App\Persistence\Models\Types\Money' not found in D:\development\projects\project\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type.php on line 174

I've tried to do this either by registering it after all Doctrine settings and using a event subscriber:

```
class DoctrineCustomTypesEventSubscriber implements Subscriber {

    public function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return [Events::postConnect];
    }

    public function postConnect(ConnectionEventArgs $args) {
        Type::addType('money', "App\Persistence\Models\Types\Money");
        Type::addType('geopoint', "App\Persistence\Models\Types\Point");
        Type::addType('geoarea', "App\Persistence\Models\Types\Area");
    }

}

$doctrineCustomTypesSubscriber = new App\Persistence\DoctrineCustomTypesEventSubscriber();
$app['db.event_manager']->addEventSubscriber($doctrineCustomTypesSubscriber);

$app->register(new Dflydev\Provider\DoctrineOrm\DoctrineOrmServiceProvider, array(
    'orm.proxies_dir' => $app['APP_ROOT_DIR'].'/app/persistence/proxies',
    'orm.em.options' => array(
        'mappings' => array(
            array(
                'type' => 'annotation',
                'namespace' => 'App\Persistence\Models',
                'path' => $app['APP_ROOT_DIR'].'/app/persistence/models',
                'use_simple_annotation_reader' => false,
            ),
        ),
    ),
));
```

**Update**

Placing the registration before all orm settings doesn't work either:

```
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\DoctrineServiceProvider(), array(
    'db.options' => array('url' => $app['APP_DB_CONN_URL']),
));

Type::addType('money', "App\Persistence\Models\Types\Money");
Type::addType('geopoint', "App\Persistence\Models\Types\Point");
Type::addType('geoarea', "App\Persistence\Models\Types\Area");
```

What am I doing wrong here?

---

Also can you tell me where do I put these registrations:

```
$em->getConnection()->getDatabasePlatform()->registerDoctrineTypeMapping(...)?
```

Answer (score 1):

The type classes should exist and be registered in autoloader, so that they can be instantiated by FQCN associated with type.

Comment: well, tried adding the registration right after I register `DoctrineServiceProvider` (see update). Nothing. The error persists.

Comment: Are classes actually exist and registered in composer? i.e. if you try `new App\Persistence\Models\Types\Area;` does it create the class?

Comment: This was the problem! The classes end with Type postfix (MoneyType, PointType and so on). Add your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.